# powershell script fails to execute

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a PS script to start a program (dtllst.exe) that requires 2 parameters in order to start.

1. a config file and
2. an application name for which the program is used for.

Script writes the current status of the execution to an output file. I am trying to use the following command to execute the script.

```
.\start.ps1 cheetah_dbmover.cfg CHEETAH
```

However the script fails with the following error.

```
1.ps1 : The term 'start.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ start.ps1 cheetah_dbmover.cfg CHEETAH
+ ~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (start.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Here's the code.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [string] $dbmover,
    [string] $appname
)

$pwd = Set-Location -Path "C:\PowerExchange"
$var = ($dbmover).Split(".")[0]

if (Test-Path "C:\PowerExchange\$appname\logs\detail.log") {
    $getfilecrtime = (Get-ChildItem "$pwd\$appname\logs\detail.log").CreationTime |
                     Get-Date -f "yyyy-MM-dd-hhmm"
    Copy-Item "$pwd\$appname\logs\detail.log" -Destination "$pwd\$appname\logs\detail_$getfilecrtime.log"
}

$config = "C:\PowerExchange\$dbmover"
$outfillepath = "C:\PowerExchange\$appname\Start\$var"
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    & cmd.exe /c C:\PowerExchange\dtllst.exe $using:config |
        Out-File -FilePath $using:outfilepath -Append
}
```

Comment: Does the tile exist in the current directory?

Comment: it seems you are not in the same directory as the script. also i'd avoid using "set-location" in a powershellscript whenever possible, i guess this bit is causing your trouble because you don't go back to the previous location in your script

Comment: Yes i am executing the script from the path where it is stored. Commented out the 'pwd' portion of the script and tried again. still no luck

Comment: I added '.\' to the front and tried again. Now I get a different error.  Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& cmd.exe /c C:\PowerExchange\dtllst.exe $Using:config | Out-File -FilePath $Using:outfilepath -append}

Comment: A Using variable cannot be retrieved. A Using variable can be used only with Invoke-Command, Start-Job, or InlineScript in the script workflow. When it is used with Invoke-Command, the Using variable is valid only if the script 
block is invoked on a remote computer.
At C:\PowerExchange\CHEETAH\Start\start.ps1:21 char:30
+ ... criptBlock {& cmd.exe /c C:\PowerExchange\dtllst.exe $Usi ...
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UsingWithoutInvokeCommand

Comment: use the arguments parameter of "invoke-command" to set $config. and maybe consider not using invoke-command in this instance, this just overcomplicates your script and i don't see the benefit in this instance

Comment: Agree with @d-j the line with invoke-command is a total overkill: use invoke command to call cmd to call exe...